# TransformXml task with InsertAfter - How to use function?

Tags: xml, xpath, msbuild, xdt-transform

I'm trying to use the `<TransformXml>` task in my web projects (.csproj/.vbproj) to Transform configuration files and other XML files. I use an msbuild script (powershell) to build and package my code and generate environment-based transformed configuration and XML files.

This all works perfectly for simple usages such as `Match`, `Condition`, `SetAttributes` and so on, but I've recently tried to be a bit clever and use an **XPath** locator to find the **last node** in a group of nodes in order to *only* set the attributes of that last node. Additionally, I want to insert a new node after the last node, with some extra attributes.

When trying this syntax:

```
<parent>
    <a xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(from)" xdt:Locator="XPath(/a[ancestor-or-self::section[last()]])" from="20130522" />
          <a xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(to)" xdt:Locator="XPath(/a[ancestor-or-self::section[last()]])" to="20130630" />
          <a xdt:Transform="InsertAfter(XPath(/a[ancestor-or-self::section[last()]]))" from="20130701" to="20140101" />
</parent>
```

on XML (shortened) that looks approximately like this:

```
<parent>
  <a from="xxx1" to="yyy1">
    <one>one</one>
    <two>two</two>
  </a>
  <a from="xxx2" to="yyy2">
    <one>one</one>
    <two>two</two>
  </a>
  <a from="xxx3" to="yyy3">
    <one>one</one>
    <two>two</two>
  </a>
</parent>
```

... I get the familiar (and expected) error

`Namespace Manager or XsltContext needed. This query has a prefix, variable, or user-defined function.`

All the answers I can find for this revolve around using code to specify a Namespace manager, which makes perfect sense - but I have no code for this process, it's all within the scope of a `TransformXml` task and plain XML. I don't know which part of the XPath query is causing this error to occur, or how I can specify the type of task I need to run.

How can I accomplish this? Is it even possible to do this type of node manipulation within a transform?

Thanks

**Edit:** I can now see that the error is occurring on the InsertAfter call and not the SetAttributes - so it's this part that appears to be causing the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so this was dead simple to resolve. `"InsertAfter"` takes an XPath expression *directly* and doesn't require the XPath function specifying - so this was a pretty simple fix! I'll leave this question up incase anyone is ever as impatient as I am :)

e.g. `InsertAfter(/parent/a[last()])`

Comment: I also found that InsertAfter works for relative nodes if you provide the value "../parent/sibling", or at least that's how SlowCheetah for VS17 worked in previewing the transform.